# Lottie AnimationView ambiguous sizes in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I'm trying to add 5 animation views into UIStackView, but I have layout issues: "Width and horizontal position are ambiguous for AnimationView". So my stackView doesn't work correct.
Here is the function where I create animation view  (I've also tried to set animation view's frame manually - nothing happens):

```
extension AnimationView  {
    public func configureCustomAnimationView(with animation: Animation?, speed: CGFloat) -> AnimationView {
        let animationView = AnimationView()
        animationView.animation = animation
        animationView.animationSpeed = speed
        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return animationView
    }
}
```

In my viewController I create 5 properties of Animation views:

```
    private var starOneAnimation = AnimationView().configureCustomAnimationView(with: Animation.starsAnimation, speed: 1)
    
    private var starTwoAnimation = AnimationView().configureCustomAnimationView(with: Animation.starsAnimation, speed: 1)
    
    private var starThreeAnimation = AnimationView().configureCustomAnimationView(with: Animation.starsAnimation, speed: 1)
    
    private var starFourAnimation = AnimationView().configureCustomAnimationView(with: Animation.starsAnimation, speed: 1)
    
    private var starFiveAnimation = AnimationView().configureCustomAnimationView(with: Animation.starsAnimation, speed: 1)
```

My stackView:

```
    private var starsStack: UIStackView = {
        let starsStack = UIStackView()
        starsStack.alignment = .center
        starsStack.axis = .horizontal
        starsStack.distribution = .equalCentering
        starsStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return starsStack
    }()
```

```
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        starsStack.addArrangedSubview(starOneAnimation)
        starsStack.addArrangedSubview(starTwoAnimation)
        starsStack.addArrangedSubview(starThreeAnimation)
        starsStack.addArrangedSubview(starFourAnimation)
        starsStack.addArrangedSubview(starFiveAnimation)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **stackView** to:

```
private var starsStack: UIStackView = {
    let starsStack = UIStackView()
    starsStack.alignment = .center
    starsStack.axis = .horizontal
    starsStack.distribution = .fillequally
    starsStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return starsStack
}()
```